# OSX 10.8.5 : gcc fails to recognise clang5 extension __builtin_mul_overflow

Tags: macos, gcc, sqlite, llvm-clang, built-in

The problem in **few words**: on a MAC OSX 10.8.5, with clang 5.1, the compiler does not seem to recognise 'clang5' extensions, in particular `__builtin_mul_overflow` comes out as `unknown builtin`. The problem arose after trying to compile the latest `sqlite3` (3.17) which insists on forcing them onto me via this conditional `#if GCC_VERSION>=5004000 || CLANG_VERSION>=4000000`. I pass the CLANG test but fail the GCC test (see below for the versions).

I have managed to bypass this problem by modifying `sqlite3.c` to not use these builtins (there is preprocessor conditional checking for CLANG and GCC_VERSION which I shorted).

**My question is**: am I mistaken that clang5 extensions are available to my system? Or might be something broken? `sqlite3.c` thinks my system should be able to know about these extra builtins, the GCC-**OR**-CLANG version-check succeeds and then the compiler (`gcc`) fails with `unknown builtin` error.

**The full details**:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0
Thread model: posix

$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0
Thread model: posix
```

The following program:

```
        # define GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__*1000000+__GNUC_MINOR__*1000+__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
# define CLANG_VERSION (__clang_major__*1000000+__clang_minor__*1000+__clang_patchlevel__)

    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void){
            printf("CLANG_VERSION: %d\n", CLANG_VERSION);
            printf("GCC_VERSION: %d\n", GCC_VERSION);
    }
```

(borrowed from sqlite3) gives the output:

```
CLANG_VERSION: 5001000
GCC_VERSION: 4002001
```

and sqlite3.c decides to use the `__builtin_mul_overflow` using this piece of code (line 28856 and others):

```
#if GCC_VERSION>=5004000 || CLANG_VERSION>=4000000
  return __builtin_mul_overflow(*pA, iB, pA);
#else
  ... code without the builtin which succeeds if check is short-circuited ...
#endif
```

Comment: `sqlite3` compiles okay with `CLANG_VERSION: 8000000`,`GCC_VERSION: 4002001`... Also what happens when you do `#if GCC_VERSION>=4002001 || CLANG_VERSION>=5001000`?

Comment: Thanks. it fails as before (it's obvious from my versions). Do you know if it's possible that my clang version string: `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)` means something other than clang5 **with clang5 extensions**?

Comment: Extensions are basically used indicate if the feature is supported by `Clang` in the current language (either as a language extension or a standard language feature) or `0` if not, and `1` if yes. Which `sqlite3` are you trying to compile from source?

Comment: Sqlite 3.17 -- basically macports tried to install it for me and failed. Then I tried manually as I described above. Is there a compiler flag which triggers these extensions? I have already compiled it and installed it (as described above). My question is whether this behaviour is normal for the compilers' versions I have or is it broken (gosh what a word) or I need some special flag. thanks

Comment: Yes, it's the check which you pointed out above — that's the trigger. I modified the code as such, and it compiles fine. I can't tell you how well the built `sqlite3` performs. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1928c3d51130f56e8fae597494c64aa4. Clearly the older Apple version of Clang does not support those functions (which apparently it doesn't know, and are removed in the gist), so excluding that seems to work.

Comment: Testing the version of clang is usually a bad idea, upstream and Apple have completely different versioning schemes... __has_builtin is the recommended way to check for builtins on clang.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a bug. In short, whoever put in the `CLANG_VERSION>=4000000` checks in `sqlite3.c` doesn't realize the Apple version of `Clang` you have (`5.1`) does not support the builtin functions:

```
__builtin_add_overflow(*pA, iB, pA);
__builtin_sub_overflow(*pA, iB, pA);
__builtin_mul_overflow(*pA, iB, pA);
```

It clearly doesn't, yet the compiler goes on thinking it does and that's when you get the error. You can either remove those checks and go with the code remaining after each `#else` in this case, or modify the `CLANG_VERSION>=` to whatever version actually does support those functions; either way it should then use the correct code while compiling.

↳ [Modified Code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1928c3d51130f56e8fae597494c64aa4) (replace lines 28834-28889 in `sqlite3.c`)

Comment: "doesn't realize the Apple version of Clang you have (5.1) does not support the builtin functions" : are you sure? Does clang 5.1 in OSX 10.8.5 actually means some other version (which sometimes happens on these apple os) of clang which does not support these extensions ?

Comment: Yes, Clang/LLVM on macOS is not the same Clang that would be on Linux. It's Apple's own modified version, and some functions being implemented have the possibility to be slightly behind their Linux counterpart.

Comment: I have posted a bug report to sqlite3 forum and will wait for their answer.